# How to consume Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 AIF web service from Java App

Tags: service, web, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I have received a MS dynamics AX 2009 AIF web service WSDL url from the client and trying to consume it from a Java client. When i connect to IIS server (web service url) and pass the SOAP request with NTLM authentication i get the error message as mention below

```
     401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

can anybody please help & let me know what it the approach one should follow?

In java i am using apache DefaultHttpClient class to establish the connection with IIS server using JCIFS library for NTLM V2 authentication. I am trying to consume the web service without using the MS dynamics AX .Net Business connector in java.

Comment: When presented with a new web service I always point a [SOAPUI application](http://www.soapui.org/) at it.  It's a free product and has helped me a lot with various types of web services.

Comment: Hi @user1776970, are you solved it? I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Check these two questions:

- [vb.Net code to use AX 2009 ReturnOrderInService web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796567/vb-net-code-to-use-ax-2009-returnorderinservice-web-service)
- [Using AIF webservices to connect to Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705173/using-aif-webservices-to-connect-to-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009)

But maybe your problem is a firewall issue, the address where the service lives is not public.

Comment: your "but maybe" clause is usually the case.